# Append data in same page in button click with react Js

Tags: reactjs

How can we list data from the array list on the same page in button click using react?

When user enter quantity setting value  text box change event

```
class ProductList extends Component {  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            CartArray:[], 
            ProductList:[],
        } 
    }

    handleInputChange = event => 
    { 
      const cart_values = event.target.name.split('-');
      let newCart = {};
      newCart["Key"]=cart_values[0]
      newCart["ProductName"]=cart_values[1]
      newCart["ProductBrand"]=cart_values[2]

      this.setState(prevState => ({CartArray: [...prevState.CartArray, newCart]}))
    }
    viewCart = () => {
       //What need to write here show data from CartArray:[] to my basket
    }
}
```

Below is my render method. Numerical text box change i am setting in state value

```
    render() {

        return ( 
            <div className="card" style={{ marginBottom: "10px"}}>
                <div>    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right"  onClick={this.viewCart}>View cart</button></div>
                                            {this.state.ProductList.map((product, key) =>(
                 <div className="card-body">
                             <div className="card-title"  key={key} value={key}>{product.ProductName}
                                <img src= {`data:image/jpeg;base64,${product.Image2}`} width="200" height="80"  />{product.Brand}
                <div>
                 <button className="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right" 
                    onClick={this.addToCart}>Add to cart</button>

                        <div>
              <input type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" onInput={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} name={`Name${key}-${product.ProductName}-${product.Brand}`} />
              </div>     
              </div>
             </div>
             </div>
             ))}

        </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: I think you are having a few div end tags extra there. You can create a new div tag in your render method that will have 2 separate divs - one for `CartArray ` and other for `ProductList`

Comment: So my question is how can i fill that newly created div with  CartArray data when i click ViewCart button?

Answer (score 0):

If by show you mean to show on screen, not inside `viewCart` but in separate method `render()`

```
render(){
        return(
                <div>
                {
                    this.state.CartArray.map((product) => {
                     <p>Key: {product.Key} </p>
                     <p>ProductName: {product.ProductName} </p>
                     <p>ProductBrand: {product.ProductBrand} </p>
                    })
                }
                </div>          
            );    
    }
```

Comment: In my component already had one render method to list product and add quantity. Then how will use this second render method?

Comment: Can you add that render() code to your question by editing?

Comment: Provided  my render method